# How to configure embedded OpenEJB container for tests properly?

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb-3.0, maven-3, openejb

This is my SLSB:

```
@Stateless
public class MyService {
  PersistenceContext(unitName = "abc")
  EntityManager em;
  public boolean exists(int id) {
    return this.em.find(Employee.class, id) != null;
  }
}
```

This is my `persistence.xml` (I'm using Glassfish v3):

```
<persistence>
  <persistence-unit name="abc">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/MyDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
          value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now I'm trying to create a test, using OpenEJB embedded container. This is my test class:

```
class MyServiceText {
  @Test
  public void testChecksExistence() throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(
        javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory"
    );
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(properties);
    // actual testing skipped
  }
}
```

I would like to use HSQL for testing. How can I instruct OpenEJB that my persistence unit `"abc"` has to point to HSQL during testing? Shall I create a new version of `persistence.xml`? Shall I use `openejb.xml`? I'm lost in their [examples and documentation](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/configuring-persistenceunits-in-tests.html).. :(

It's a Maven-3 project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest placing a file named `jndi.properties` in `src/test/resources` for your OpenEJB configuration. This will then be available in the test classpath, you can then use the no-argument contructor of InitialContext to lookup datasources and ejbs. An example configuration looks like this, I'm using mysql for my datasource:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory

myDS=new://Resource?type=DataSource
myDS.JdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
myDS.JdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
myDS.JtaManaged=true
myDS.DefaultAutoCommit=false
myDS.UserName=root
myDS.Password=root
```

OpenEJB should then automatically replace the reference in persistence.xml with this datasource, if this is the only datasource then this should work even if the names are different.

**Edit:** Persistence unit settings

According to the [documentation you referenced](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/configuring-persistenceunits-in-tests.html) it should also be possible to configure persistence unit properties through jndi.properties:

```
abc.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
abc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

I haven't tested this myself since I'm using mysql for both tests and normal executions, only with different database names. Please let me know if this works, I've been thinking about replacing mysql in my testcases too.

Comment: örn Thanks, could you please indicate in your answer how can I configure Hibernate properties for this data source (or persistence unit).. Or maybe you can give a link where this information is disclosed?

Comment: örn Maybe you can help with this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052898? Thanks