# Why datasource is not found in JNDI after injection from jndi.properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, jpa, openejb

This is my `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence>
  <persistence-unit name="MyUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/abcDS</jta-data-source>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is `jndi.properties` file from `src/test/resources` which is supposed to create a datasource during testing, since a real application server with a real datasource is absent:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory
jdbc/abcDS=new://Resource?type=DataSource
jdbc/abcDS.JdbcDriver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc/abcDS.JdbcUrl=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
jdbc/abcDS.JtaManaged=true
jdbc/abcDS.DefaultAutoCommit=false
jdbc/abcDS.UserName=sa
jdbc/abcDS.Password=
```

This is the test class:

```
public class FinderTest {
  @BeforeClass
  public static void startEJB() throws Exception {
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    ic.lookup("jdbc/abcDS");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the datasource is not created and this is what I keep seeing:

```
[...]
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "jdbc/abcDS" not found.
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:193)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:150)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:124)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.ContextWrapper.lookup(ContextWrapper.java:115)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at com.XXX.FinderTest.startEJB(FinderTest.java:31)
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

ps. By the way it works this way (what's going on???):

```
ic.lookup("java:/openejb/Resource/jdbc/abcDS");
```

Comment: @Thorbjørn There is no "server", it's a test running cycle.. Actually, it's an embedded OpenEJB instead of a real application server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be found if you lookup `openejb:Resource/jdbc/abcDS`

As well you can get [injection in your TestCase](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/local-client-injection.html).  Basically, you:

1. add an empty `src/test/resources/META-INF/application-client.xml` or `ejb-jar.xml`
2. Annotate your test with `@LocalClient`
3. Call `initialContext.bind("inject", this)`

See the `testcase-injection` example in the [examples.zip](http://archive.apache.org/dist/openejb/3.1.3/openejb-examples-3.1.3.zip)

**EDIT**  If the lookup still fails, post your log output (the console output).